# Integration using Sympy

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-integration

I want to evaluate an integral of the form:

[image: Equation]

using python `sympy`, however, I am not able to do so.
This is what I have implemented:

```
import sympy as sym
r,a,b = sym.symbols('r,a,b')
I = r/sym.sqrt((a-r)*(r-b))
I_1 = sym.integrate (I,r)
print (I_1)
```

The result that I am getting is: `Integral(r/sqrt(-(-a + r)*(-b + r)), r)`

Thus, it is not evaluating the integral, rather just simplifying the equation.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: is that an exact function?

Comment: Are you allowed to apply assumptions? For example, `r` is real, `a,b` real and positive?

Comment: it seems to be an [elliptic integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) of 1st kind which is still integrable...upto some manipulation

Comment: a and b are positive and a > b. This is actually to show that an observer falling into a Reissner-Nordstrom black hole will reach Cauchy Horizon in finite amount of proper time.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to compute an antiderivative with a substitution:

```
In [1]: import sympy as sym
   ...: r,a,b = sym.symbols('r,a,b')
   ...: I = r/sym.sqrt((a-r)*(r-b))
   ...: I_1 = sym.integrate (I,r)
   ...: print (I_1)
Integral(r/sqrt(-(-a + r)*(-b + r)), r)

In [2]: t = symbols('t')

In [3]: tsubs = r - (a+b)/2

In [4]: Integral(I, r)
Out[4]: 
⌠                        
⎮          r             
⎮ ──────────────────── dr
⎮   __________________   
⎮ ╲╱ (a - r)⋅(-b + r)    
⌡                        

In [5]: Integral(I, r).transform(tsubs, t)
Out[5]: 
⌠                                 
⎮           a   b                 
⎮           ─ + ─ + t             
⎮           2   2                 
⎮ ───────────────────────────── dt
⎮     _________________________   
⎮    ╱ ⎛a   b    ⎞ ⎛a   b    ⎞    
⎮   ╱  ⎜─ - ─ - t⎟⋅⎜─ - ─ + t⎟    
⎮ ╲╱   ⎝2   2    ⎠ ⎝2   2    ⎠    
⌡                                 

In [6]: Integral(I, r).transform(tsubs, t).doit()
Out[6]: 
  ⎛⎧    ⎛         _________________⎞                         ⎞     ⎛⎧    ⎛         _________________⎞                         ⎞                              
  ⎜⎪    ⎜        ╱        1        ⎟       2            2    ⎟     ⎜⎪    ⎜        ╱        1        ⎟       2            2    ⎟                              
a⋅⎜⎨asin⎜2⋅t⋅   ╱  ─────────────── ⎟  for a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  > 0⎟   b⋅⎜⎨asin⎜2⋅t⋅   ╱  ─────────────── ⎟  for a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  > 0⎟      ________________________
  ⎜⎪    ⎜      ╱    2            2 ⎟                         ⎟     ⎜⎪    ⎜      ╱    2            2 ⎟                         ⎟     ╱  2            2      2 
  ⎝⎩    ⎝    ╲╱    a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  ⎠                         ⎠     ⎝⎩    ⎝    ╲╱    a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  ⎠                         ⎠   ╲╱  a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  - 4⋅t  
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── + ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ───────────────────────────
                              2                                                                2                                               2             

In [7]: Integral(I, r).transform(tsubs, t).doit().subs(t, tsubs)
Out[7]: 
  ⎛⎧    ⎛                     _________________⎞                         ⎞     ⎛⎧    ⎛                     _________________⎞                         ⎞        ____________________________________
  ⎜⎪    ⎜  ⎛  a   b    ⎞     ╱        1        ⎟       2            2    ⎟     ⎜⎪    ⎜  ⎛  a   b    ⎞     ╱        1        ⎟       2            2    ⎟       ╱                                  2 
a⋅⎜⎨asin⎜2⋅⎜- ─ - ─ + r⎟⋅   ╱  ─────────────── ⎟  for a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  > 0⎟   b⋅⎜⎨asin⎜2⋅⎜- ─ - ─ + r⎟⋅   ╱  ─────────────── ⎟  for a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  > 0⎟      ╱   2            2     ⎛  a   b    ⎞  
  ⎜⎪    ⎜  ⎝  2   2    ⎠   ╱    2            2 ⎟                         ⎟     ⎜⎪    ⎜  ⎝  2   2    ⎠   ╱    2            2 ⎟                         ⎟     ╱   a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  - 4⋅⎜- ─ - ─ + r⎟  
  ⎝⎩    ⎝                ╲╱    a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  ⎠                         ⎠     ⎝⎩    ⎝                ╲╱    a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  ⎠                         ⎠   ╲╱                        ⎝  2   2    ⎠  
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── + ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────── - ─────────────────────────────────────────
                                    2                                                                            2                                                            2                    

In [8]: factor(piecewise_fold(_), deep=True)
Out[8]: 
⎧      ⎛                    _________________⎞         ⎛                    _________________⎞                                           
⎪      ⎜                   ╱        1        ⎟         ⎜                   ╱        1        ⎟                                           
⎪a⋅asin⎜(-a - b + 2⋅r)⋅   ╱  ─────────────── ⎟   b⋅asin⎜(-a - b + 2⋅r)⋅   ╱  ─────────────── ⎟                                           
⎨      ⎜                 ╱    2            2 ⎟         ⎜                 ╱    2            2 ⎟                                           
⎪      ⎝               ╲╱    a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  ⎠         ⎝               ╲╱    a  - 2⋅a⋅b + b  ⎠     ____________________             2    
⎪───────────────────────────────────────────── + ───────────────────────────────────────────── - ╲╱ -(-a + r)⋅(-b + r)   for (a - b)  > 0
⎩                      2                                               2
```

The result comes out with a condition that is basically equivalent to `a != b` (if a and b are assumed real). You can use `.args[0][0]` to extract just the expression part.

Comment: How did you chose `tsubs = r - (a+b)/2`?

Comment: The substitution is basically just completing the square.

Answer (score 2):

`sympy` cannot compute this integral.

You're looking at a manually created indefinite integral of:

[image: Integral]

which is now complex.

Or a maxima created integal of:

[image: maxima]

---

Either way, all algorithms and options have been exhausted, and it failed on every try. Some integrals are just too difficult for `sympy` to solve.

> [integral-calculator.com](https://www.integral-calculator.com/#expr=r%2Fsqrt%28%28a-r%29%28r-b%29%29&intvar=r)

Comment: Thank you for your help! I looked into this but this doesn't yield the answer I was looking for. I did visit this website before posting the question here.

Answer (score 0):

To simplifying integral you can use:

```
sympy.pprint(sympy.Integral(I, x))
```

To solve integral you can use:

```
sympy.pprint(integrate(I, x))
```

Comment: This does not solve it

Comment: if you try this sympy.pprint(integrate('sin(x)**2', x)) sympy solve this integral and to solve definite integral use sympy.pprint(integrate('sin(x)**2', (x, from, to)))

Comment: Thank you for you help but this actually gave me the same result that I have been getting before.

Comment: Maybe this repo can help you https://github.com/andrwgldmn/SimpleCalcPython/blob/linux-py2.7/eng.py